# How to find last line in string (package.json)

Tags: javascript, string, package.json

I have been trying to add new fields at the end of the package.json. 
I can't use

- **JSON.parse**
- add new item
- **JSON.stringfy**

approach because it gives me single line output. I don't want to change other lines in the package.json in git diff I only need to see new property that's all.

So I tried to find last line after getting package.json in string format. 
These are the steps

- Remove closing curly bracket
- Find last line (trim empty spaces and enters)
- Add comma
- Add new property at the next line
- Add closing curly bracket

This works however json also might contain number, null, booleans (true/false) at the and. How can I detect these if this is the case ? Also please let me know any other type json might have.

---

First approach, thanks to **@jonrsharpe**'s contribution works like a charm.

```
packageJSON = `{
    "abc": "def",
    "qwe": true
}
`
function addNewField(packageJSON){

    const obj = JSON.parse(packageJSON)
    obj["newField"] = {
        z: "zzz",
        x: 100
    }
    return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2)

}

const resultStr = addNewField(packageJSON)
/*
"{
  "abc": "def",
  "qwe": true,
  "newField": {
    "z": "zzz",
    "x": 100
  }
}"
*/
```

Comment: *"it gives me single line output"* - so try `JSON.stringify(value, null, 2)`?

Comment: You are the life saver. Amazing ! @jonrsharpe